# Falkon Browser error

Tags: browser

I installed the Falkon browser in Ubuntu 18.04. There is a bug in speed dial. Bookmarks are generated incorrectly. There is no name or thumbnail of the website. What can I do to make it work properly?

Comment: You will probably want to [file a bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Falkon) with the development team rather than ask here 

Answer (score 1):

Falkon requests that you report bugs and feature requests at [the KDE Bugzilla](https://www.falkon.org/development/) website